# jquery validation engine with dropkick

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-validation-engine, jquery-dropkick

I'm having problems with getting the Posabsolute **jquery validation engine** plugin to work with Jamie lotterings **dropkick** plugin. 
I think i am having this issue due to dropkick is hiding the original `<select>` -element. And displays different `<div>`-s instead.

This is how i bind the validationEngine to my form `$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".theForm").validationEngine('attach'); 
});` and this is how i append validation to my `<select>` `<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlAttribute" CssClass="dk validate[required]" />`

Do anyone have a working solution for these two plugins?

Comment: Gay got the same problem

Comment: It would be great if you can create a working demo of your code.